# jquery delay changes queued function closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, scope, delay

I have a very simple test page that tests jquery (1.4.2) queue and delay.

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        $('#test')
        //.delay(50)
        .queue(function(next) {
            console.log(i);
            next();
        });
    }
```

Now when I run this code in FF with firebug, I get what I expected, 1 ~ 5.

However, if I un-comment delay, I got 6 five times instead?

Can someone please help me clarify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `i` is a single variable stored *one* time and shared by all iterations of the loop.  Without the [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) you're using the value of `i` **right then**, so it's what you expect.  *With* the [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) however, you're using what the value is *later*...and later it's what it ended up as at the end of the loop, 6.

Answer (score 4):

[@Nick provides an excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201907/jquery-delay-changes-queued-function-closure/5201952#5201952) for *why* it behaves like this.

For completeness, you can "fix" this by capturing the current value of `i` in a new scope. JavaScript has only function scope, so you have to use a function to capture the value. E.g. you can use an *immediate function*:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('#test')
    .delay(50)
    .queue((function(index) {
        return function(next) {
            console.log(index);
            next();
        }
    }(i))); // <- function gets called directly with `i` and the returned
            //    function is passed to queue.
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4kRZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Well for the following code in firebug console on stackoverflow

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('#custom-header')
        //.delay(50)
        .queue(function(next) {
        console.log(i);
        next();
        });
}
```

On console, you get result

```
1
2
3
4
5
[div#custom-header]
```

And for code

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('#custom-header')
        .delay(50)
        .queue(function(next) {
        console.log(i);
        next();
        });
}
```

You get result

```
[div#custom-header]
6
6
6
6
6
```

[Explanation]:

From this we can conclude that `dealay(50)` delays the the evaluation of the function inside queue so `[div#custom-header]` is printed first and `i` is printed which is all `6` (by the moment) because the loop (which is not delayed) is evaluated first (only the printing function inside queue is delayed).

Comment: While your code does show the correct results, it doesn't explain *why* it shows `6` :) I believe that's what the OP is after.

Comment: @Nick well I have tried to add hypothetical explanation below